# Ошибка в node.js c Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, gulp

[image: Ошибка которую не знаю как решить]

Здравствуйте. Я только учусь. Установил node.js. Также установил gulp. Хотел проверить всё ли работает и столкнулся с проблемой. Ошибкой об какой в видео не расказано. Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь! Все файлы сохранены как js и html. Без txt.

**Это package.json**

```
{
  "name": "work",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My First Gulp Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Taras P",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vinyl": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

**Вот что написал в файле gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('mytask', function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
});
```

**Ошибка:**

```
PS D:\Work> gulp task
module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'vinyl'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Vorteri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-
util\index.js:2:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто запустите команду — `npm install` из той же директории, где находится файл `package.json`

потом

```
gulp mytask
```